# Is it possible for function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ have a maximum at every point in a countable dense subset of its domain?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible for function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ have a maximum at  every point in a countable dense subset of its domain ? The motivation for this question is I have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ where the number of maxima increases with $n$ and I am interested to know what happens to the sequence of functions.

PS : every function of the sequence has a finite number of maxima.

EDIT : $f$ should not be constant function.

Comment: What if the function $f$ was constant?... ;) Or do you want to have the set of maximas to be countable? If you can allow ''more'' maximas, the constant function would be an example of one such function.

Comment: @Patrick: Or, if you insist on countable, the characteristic function of the rationals.

Comment: @Patrick : maxima means second derivative should be negative.

Comment: @Rajesh: So you want your function to be twice differentiable. Please include that in the statement of your question.

Comment: @Yuval : Ok, i do not need it to be differentiable but i do not want constant function either.

Comment: I was just about to write the example that Jonas Meyer suggested. Do you need anything to be satisfied by $f$ or you just wanted to know if some whatever-function $f$ would do the trick?

Comment: @Patrick : thank you for the comment about constant function.

Comment: The word *maxima* is the **plural** of *maximum*. Maxima = maximums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) has a strict local maximum at each rational number.

I believe the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is another example.

---

[Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27907/countability-of-local-maxima-on-continuous-real-valued-functions) on this site posed the problem of showing that if $f$ is continuous and not monotone on any interval, then $f$ has a local maximum at each point in a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're quick, aren't you. XD

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible for the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ where each one is smooth to converge to such a function ?

Comment: @Rajesh: The Weierstrass function is a uniform limit of smooth functions.

Answer (score 3):

Sample paths of Brownian motion have this property (with probability $1$), see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Qualitative_properties).

Comment: See the third item in that subsection (Qualitative properties).