# Showing range is countable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.  For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta$, for every $y \in N(x, \delta)$ ($N$ stands for neighborhood) $f(y) \geq f(x)$.

Show that the range of $f$ is countable.

Comment: Please do not give orders.  I'm sure you will find people are more willing to help if you just ask!

Comment: thank you for your better fashion!

Comment: No problem. The grammar to your post is still not quite right.  If there is anything you would like to change, please do so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose $a$ is in the range of $f(x)$. Then if $x_0$ is any number such that $f(x_0) = a$, one can find an interval $[b,c]$ containing $x_0$ with $b$ and $c$ rational such that $f(x) \geq a$ on $[b,c]$. Thus $a \mapsto (b,c)$ gives a mapping from the range of $f(x)$ to ${\mathbb Q} \times {\mathbb Q}$, and this mapping is clearly injective. Hence the range of $f$ is countable.

Comment: Simple and nice.

Comment: How come the mapping is injective? You said "clearly" but I am not quite convinced... though if I would the proof would be pretty!

EDIT: duh... I worked it out. Though you could've added one more line... It is not that much obvious.

Comment: @Patrick: It looks like it could be an assignment so maybe I shouldn't write *too* much.

Comment: Okay, cool then.

Answer (score 2):

In other words, $f$ has a local minimum everywhere. More generally, the same result holds if $f$ has a local extremum everywhere; according to [this](http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/home/problems/pdf/uitwerking-2010-4.pdf) (**Problem 2010-4/B**), the result can be found in several places in the literature (a proof is also provided).
Interestingly, as a corollary in the case where $f$ is further continuous, we get an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31718/continuous-function-with-local-maxima-everywhere-but-no-global-maxima/44463) (note my answer given there).

EDIT (elaborating on the second part): Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and has a local extremum everywhere. From the latter property, it follows that the range of $f$ is countable. Hence we conclude from the intermediate value theorem that $f$ must be constant (for otherwise the range would be uncountable, a contradiction).