# Cute undergraduate real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing range is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45035/showing-range-is-countable)

I was going through my old notebooks and found this. I thought it was good enough to share.

**Problem:** Let $f(x)$ be a function $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, with the only restriction on it being that it has a local extremum at each point. Prove it has countable range.

Comment: Bravo! Great poser!

Comment: So, was this problem brought to your attention by a cute undergraduate?

Comment: @WillJagy Unfortunately not :(.

Comment: This is similar to the question [Showing range is countable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45035/showing-range-is-countable).  I actually voted to close as duplicate, but perhaps hastily as here it is a little more general, assuming extremum rather than local minimum.  [Shai Covo's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/45047/) there is on this generalization.

Comment: @Jonas: one of the answers in the question you linked answers the case of arbitrary extrema (and gives references, too).

Comment: It is literally the same proof. You can do the proof for local minimums from the link, then do the proof for maximums (which is the same). Then notice the range is a subset of the union of two countable sets. Further, if this function is continuous, it is constant.