# Is $f$ constant when each point is local minimum or maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a connected topological space and $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Further, we know that all $x\in X$ are local extrema. Does that imply that $f$ is constant?

I think in case $X$ is second-countable that should be the case because of the proof of Theorem 2 [here](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/bhrnds/publ_papers/BGN.pdf) (it is only stated for separable metric spaces there but I think the same proof works for second-countable spaces). But what about an arbitrary connected topological space $X$?

Comment: Example 6 in the linked paper should answer this question, I suppose.

Comment: @daw Thank you. That answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper you link gives a counterexample already. Consider $X = [0,1]^2$ ordered lexicographically, i.e. $(x,y) < (x',y') \iff (x < x' \text{ or } (x = x' \text{ and y < y'}))$, and give $X$ the order topology. This is a connected space. Then the projection $p:(x,y) \mapsto x$ is a continuous function, and every point of $X$ is a local extremum. But $p$ is not constant.

Comment: @daw pointed that already out. But you a wrong in saying that every point is a local maximum. The point $(0,1)$ is no local maximum but a local minimum.

Comment: Why do you say that the projection is continuous?

Comment: @Crostul The preimage of $(a,b)$ is $(a,b) \times [0,1]$, which is open in the order topology: if $a < x < b$, then let $a < u < x < v < b$, so that $(x,y)$ is in the "interval" between $(u,0)$ and $(v,1)$ (which is wholly in $(a,b) \times [0,1]$).

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain He pointed this out in a comment, comments aren't for answers (I made this answer CW anyway). Thanks for the remark about maximum/minimum, I was a bit hasty here.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Can you find a counter-example where every point indeed is a local maximum?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain This one isn't possible actually, [see this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31718/continuous-function-with-local-maxima-everywhere-but-no-global-maxima) (And now I feel silly when I stated that every point was a local maximum...)